# How to hide a div if a value from db matches - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to hide a `<div>` element if the value `is_admin === "0"` in table admins.

**Here is my Controller Code**

```
    function dashboard(Request $request){
    $data = ['LoggedUserInfo'=>Admin::where('id','=', session('LoggedUser'))->first()];
    $count = \DB::table('candidates')->count();
    $count2 = \DB::table('admins')->count();

    $data1 = \DB::table('admins');
    $data1 = $data1->paginate(10);


    return view('dashboard', $data,compact('count','count2','data1'));
}
```

I want to hide this div if `is_admin === "0"`

```
<div class="c1" id="l1">
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
  <p class="p">No. of Candidates: {{$count}}</p>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <p class="p">No. of Sub Admins: {{$count2}}</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use an iniline if like `($is_admin === '0' ? 'display:none': '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if($is_admin !== '0')
  <div class="c1" id="l1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <p class="p">No. of Candidates: {{$count}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
         <p class="p">No. of Sub Admins: {{$count2}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if($is_admin === '0')
 // show nothing
@else
  <div class="c1" id="l1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <p class="p">No. of Candidates: {{$count}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
         <p class="p">No. of Sub Admins: {{$count2}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endif
```